# How to cool tank water in summer?

Tags: water

My home is supplied water from a well, that gets stored in a roof-top tank. The problem is that during these summer days (45°C), the stored water heats up and gets scalding hot. Its impossible to shower or to even to wash my hands!

I need a solution to this. Is there something like a water chiller which can cool the water as it flows into the house. I know there are whole house tankless water *heaters*, I basically need something that does the reverse job of that.

Comment: Have you tried insulating the tank yet?

Comment: Refrigeration is inefficient and expensive. Your best approach is to prevent solar heating in the first place.

Comment: you could try using a system similar to a swamp cooler, or the canvas water canteen that you hang on the outside of a car ... cover the tank with fabric, or something that can be made wet .... pump small amount of water over the tank to make the covering wet ... natural evaporation will cool the tank

Answer (score 2):

*An aquarium chiller* is meant to cool down a tank of water. You will find different types for different sizes of tanks and how much they need to cool the the tank.

However you may get a cheaper cooling effect by simply putting the tank in the shade by for example building a simple shed around it. This will prevent the direct heating from the sun.

Comment: I would agree that shading is probably the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Is the heat coming from the sun, the outdoor temperature, or the heat from being inside an attic?

If it's from the sun, you need to put a roof or something that keeps the sun off the tank.

If it's from the outdoor temperature, then you need to insulate the tank.

If it's from the heat of being inside an attic, then you need to increase the net free area of the attic/roof intake (usually soffits in the USA) and exhaust vents.

Depending on the outdoor temperature, you could install a coil of copper pipe that you run the water through to make the temperature of the water the same as the outdoor air. Set the coil up to run a fan through it, or directly on the least sunny side of your house like a giant radiator.

If the outdoor air temp is the problem, then using the ground is your best heatsink. Burying a lot of pipe a few feet underground and running your water through it would remove the heat.

Running a circulation pump through your DIY radiator on a timer might give you better results than trying to run all the water through it as you use it.

Best thing would be to just move your tank to the basement.

Answer (score 0):

If the water from the well is pumped to your home, why not move the roof tank inside the home or replace it with a bladder tank that is mounted inside your home away from the sun. More information please.

Answer (score 0):

If the temp of the water coming out of the well is say 25 C and it is being heated to 45 C in the rooftop tank, then you must not be using much water compared to the volume of the tank. That is, the water in the tank has a long residence time.

The simplest solution might be to only fill the tank half full or less so you use the water before it gets too hot.

Answer (score 0):

All are great answers A roof for shade is a plus. Walls and insulation, would be the next step. try to use metal, for materials. And paint it silver to reflect heat away. We use a oil based silver on bee hives works great to cool them. They make foil faced foam insulation. The pipe is under ground,so i would not due much with that. If that is not enough. Add a 50 gallon tank in basement to store water.And add to that. if you need to cool more. These are the steps, i would go until it works. Cooling 50 less expensive than whole tank.

Answer (score 0):

You could control water 'inlet' of the tank, if so you could keep the tank low, and run the pump to replenish only when you need water, doing so you'll add cold water when water is required, water will mix into the tank arriving cooler.

Another thing you can do is to shed the tank itself, so sulight won't hit it directly and water will stay cooler.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the water warm but just less hot?  An interesting but complicated idea would be to attach a sterling engine/generator to the side of the tank or place the warm side of the sterling engine in the water.  "Burning/scalding" hot water starts at 53C so there is at least an 8C difference between the tank and the ambient air, possibly more.

A sterling engine would run from the differential in tempratures providing energy that you could use.  A side effect of running the engine would be the transfer of heat from the tank to the surrounding air, cooling the water to a more tolerable temprature. It would never allow the water to get cooler than the air though.

In the winter, it could run backwards if the water is colder than the air.  It would also cause the water to freeze faster if the  air is below freezing.  In all cases, it would always cause the water temperature to move toward the air temperature.